# Build heartbeat service with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5

I want to build a heatbeat service for my angular2 website. A remote device is  the host of the website and the client should be able to detect if the device is not reachable/offline.
The service should  poll periodically the (webserver) remote device.

*I know that a failed HTTP-Call cannot be directly equated with the online/offline status of the whole device, but for my requirements that should be enough.*

Currently I'm using the following Observable which is placed inside of an angular service:

```
  public getStatus() {
    return  this.http.get(this.config.apiEndpoint + this.fileName)
      .map(() => { return '1'; })
      .timeout(500)
      .catch(() => {return '0';})
      .retry()
      .delay(1500)
      .repeat();
  }
```

The target of the observable is just an almost empty file on the webserver.
A component subscribes to the observable/service and then shows a notification if the device status changes.

In principle the Observable works, but it provides a continuous stream of ones (online) and zeros (offline) to the component which subscribed to it. Now I have to add some logic to the component (and every other component which uses this service) to handle for example two successive zeros, that a notification is only shown once.

It would be much cleaner and a better separation of concerns if the service could do this extra work and only provide a result (to the component) when the status of the device changed. I also tried to use a `Observable.timer` with a `flatMap` but failed to get it working, but I expect rxjs provides a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `distinctUntilChanged` operator, it will ensure to pass only distinct values.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I added the mentioned operator and it works as expected.

Comment: Edit: So it solved my problem partially,  but then I realized that a component itself have to know if it should ignore the first response, because the service can't distinguish it's subscribers. So, problem solved, thanks!